# How to post a value to a webpage in a datalist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

i want to post the Prd_id to the webpage Products.aspx as in the code

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server"
         DataKeyField="Prd_id" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <a href='Products.aspx?prdid=<%# Eval("Prd_id") %>'>Add to Cart</a>
         </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a hidden field to store the selected product id:

HTML:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addProduct(prid) {
            // assign the product ID to the hidden field's value
            document.getElementById("<%= hidProductId.ClientID %>").value = prid;
        }
    </script>

    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="Prd_id" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnAdd" runat="server" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" OnClientClick="<%# "addProduct('" + Eval("Prd_id") + "');" %>" ></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>

    <asp:HiddenField ID="hidProductId" runat="server" />
```

Code behind:

```
    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var productId = hidProductId.Value;
    }
```

Comment: You can try to use a button with PostbackURL property

Comment: i dont want to have to use javascript